# When to use "contro di" as opposed to only "contro"?

Tags: prepositions

I know it is correct to say "contro di lui", but "contro il nemico". Why? Is it because in the first case the object is a pronoun and in the second case it is a noun?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/contro

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when using it with a personal pronoun you need to use the preposition "di", while with a noun you can use it with an article or even without, if it's a first name.

- Contro DI lui (personal pronoun)
- Contro UN ragazzo (noun)
- Contro Luca (first name)